# MPI GRAPH : Send Messages to neighbours except where it came from

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed, openmpi

I have a funny situation here.   Am trying to have a node in graph to send a message  to all its neighbors except for its parent ( node which just sent a message ) . The code I have seems to show that this particular node( n  )  does receive messages from all its neighbours(correct ) . The issue is for sending, only the first message that arrived gets sent. All others are ignored.
**NB : This is a star topology with all other nodes sending to central node 0
Here is example output**  :-

```
  0    received  1 from 1
  0    received  2 from 2
  0    received  3 from 3
  0    received  4 from 4
  0    received  5 from 5
  0    received  6 from 6


  Having correctly  received these values, node zero(0 ) is expected to send each message to all others in the following pattern  i.e. :-

      0 sent   1 to 2
      0 sent   1 to 3
      0 sent   1 to 4
      0 sent   1 to 5
      0 sent   1 to 6

   , 
      0 sent   2 to 1
      0 sent   2 to 3
      0 sent   2 to 4
      0 sent   2 to 5
      0 sent   2 to 6
    ,
      0 sent   3 to 2
      0 sent   3 to 1
      0 sent   3 to 4
      0 sent   3 to 5
      0 sent   3 to 6

, etc .
```

I unfortunately get otherwise, only the first  message gets sent to other nodes and the rest ignored.i.e. if 1 get received first by 0, I get  only the following output  :-

```
  0 sent   1 to 2
  0 sent   1 to 3
  0 sent   1 to 4
  0 sent   1 to 5
  0 sent   1 to 6
```

All other messages are not sent.

Here is how the code in the central node of the star-graph topology looks like  :-

```
     MPI_Recv(&message , 1 , MPI_INT ,  MPI_ANY_SOURCE , echo_tag, COMM, &status ); 

//Sending just received message to neighbors, except to parent :-

    parent = status.MPI_SOURCE;

    for ( int l = 0 ; l< neighbourcount ; l++ ){
         int current_neighbour =  neighbours[l];
          if (  current_neighbour != parent ){
                    MPI_Send(&message , 1 , MPI_INT , current_neighbour , tag, COMM );
          }
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to tell from the last snippet of code, but do you have some kind of "outer loop" that iterates through the received messages and then send them one by one to the appropriate neighbours or do you immediately send  any received message then go back to `MPI_Recv()`? Could you please put more code in order to get a better idea on what the codes is (not) doing ?

Comment: Hi, thanks.I just edited the code  I have no outer loop . I seem to understand you way of thinking though. You seem to suggest I put all the code in a loop that repeats cout_neighbours - 1 times ?

Comment: Yes! Should probably use something like `for (messageIdx = 0; messageIdx < TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_EXPECTED_MESSAGES; ++messageIdx) { MPI_Recv(); /* the for loop for sending to the neighbours */ } `

Comment: Thats logical, but the code then hangs after the is done. Even though it hangs just on 1st iteration, all messages have been received.

Comment: Since you have 6 neighbours for node 0, how about defining `int message[6];` and calling `MPI_Recv(message , 6, MPI_INT ,  MPI_ANY_SOURCE , echo_tag, COMM, &status );` only once, before entering the outer for loop ? Also, you might need to change the call to `MPI_Send()` to something like `MPI_Send(&message[messageIdx] , 1 , MPI_INT , current_neighbour , tag, COMM );`. As mentioned [here](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Recv.html) you should probably use `MPI_Get_count()` to get the actual `TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_EXPECTED_MESSAGES` before entering the outer for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need a double for for the job, like this:

```
int j;
for(j = 0; j < neighbourcount; ++j) {
   for ( int l = 0 ; l< neighbourcount ; l++ ){
         int current_neighbour =  neighbours[l];
          if (  current_neighbour != parent ){
                    MPI_Send(/*send j*/ , 1 , MPI_INT , current_neighbour , tag, COMM );
          }
    }
}
```